# Trying to sum from a generated list

Tags: list, haskell

Hello I recently started studying Haskell and I am trying to make a little program that given a function it creates a list and then I want to take the sum of the list:

```
f a b c = a+b+c

my_sum [] = 0
my_sum (x:xs) = x + my_sum xs

my_list f a b c = [f a b x |x <- [1..c]]
```

I am trying to take the sum of the list like this but I always get errors

```
  *Main> my_sum [my_list f 1 1 4]

<interactive>:13:1:
    No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of `my_sum'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [t0])
    In the expression: my_sum [my_list f 1 1 4]
    In an equation for `it': it = my_sum [my_list f 1 1 4]

<interactive>:13:9:
    No instance for (Num t0) arising from a use of `my_list'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variabl
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
      ...plus three others
    In the expression: my_list f 1 1 4
    In the first argument of `my_sum', namely `[my_list f 1 1 4]'
    In the expression: my_sum [my_list f 1 1 4]
```

can you help me?

Comment: `my_list` has 5 arguments but you are only providing 4.

Comment: @Khaelid I edited the question. I had copied the wrong version of my code.

Comment: You say "_given a function_ it creates a list", but you're not giving it (`my_list`) a function (but you did before the edit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_sum` takes one argument, a list of numbers. Since `my_list` returns a list, wrapping its result in a list results in a list of lists (mismatching `my_sum`):

```
my_sum [my_list f 1 1 5] -- argument has type Num a => [[a]]
my_sum (my_list f 1 1 5) -- this is right
```

Comment: Original `myList` takes only four arguments.

Comment: @Yuuri Edited to match.